# Filter multiple array object with multiple property

Tags: javascript, typescript, underscore.js, lodash

Im trying to create a filter function where it can return a result of data that matches the value that i am looking for , from the given set of string keys

example of array:

```
let data = [
 { id:1 , data:{ name:"sample1",address:{ cat:"business" } } },
 { id:2 , data:{ name:"sample2",address:{ cat:"office"  }  } },
 { id:3 , data:{ name:"sample3",address:{ cat:"office"  } } },
 { id:4 , data:{ name:"sample4",address:{ cat:"office"  }  } }
 { id:5 , data:{ name:"sample5",address:{ cat:"home"  } } }
 { id:6 , data:{ name:"sample6",address:{ cat:"home"  }  } }
]



function filter( collection , value ,key ){
  //code 
}


let result = filter( data , "business" , [ "data","address","cat" ] )

console.log(result)
```

expected result is

> { id:1 , data:{ name:"sample1",address:{ cat:"business" } } },

Comment: You want to search for any of the of key, **right?** Mean to say, sometimes key may be **id, name, address** also?

Comment: No the key is the exact address of the value in the array. it could be also string or object you can modify it.

Comment: Very nice question

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `filter` to search for the data. Use `reduce` to construct the keys.

Note: `filter` returns an array of matched elements. If you prefer the first match only, you can use `find`

```js
const data = [
  { id: 1, data: { name: "sample1", address:{ cat: "business" } } },
  { id: 2, data: { name: "sample2", address:{ cat: "office" } } },
  { id: 3, data: { name: "sample3", address:{ cat: "office" } } },
  { id: 4, data: { name: "sample4", address:{ cat: "office" } } },
  { id: 5, data: { name: "sample5", address:{ cat: "home" } } },
  { id: 6, data: { name: "sample6", address:{ cat: "home" } } }
]

const filter = (collection, keys, value) => 
  collection.filter(o => keys.reduce((c, v) => c[v] || {}, o) === value)
const result = filter(data, ["data", "address", "cat"], "business")

console.log(result)
```

Comment: Might help to make a note about returning an array instead of a single item

Comment: This is  one am looking for thank you Eddie .. its very native .. no need lodash.. :)

Comment: Crazometer, you right. I noted it above. @JakeGarbo Happy to help :)

Answer (score 1):

```
function filter( collection , value ,key ){
  const getNestedObjectValue = (nestedObject, propertyPath) => {
      return propertyPath.reduce((obj, key) =>
          (obj && obj[key] !== 'undefined') ? obj[key] : undefined, nestedObject);

  };
  return collection.filter( item => getNestedObjectValue(item, key) === value);
}
```

The filter function will return an array of matching object(s) when there is a match and an empty array when there is no match

```
let result = filter( data , "business" , [ "data","address","cat" ] );

console.log(result); // [{"id":1,"data":{"name":"sample1","address":{"cat":"business"}}}]

let result2 = filter( data , "office" , [ "data","address","cat" ] );

console.log(result2); //[{"id":2,"data":{"name":"sample2","address":{"cat":"office"}}},{"id":3,"data":{"name":"sample3","address":{"cat":"office"}}},{"id":4,"data":{"name":"sample4","address":{"cat":"office"}}}]

let result3 = filter( data , "vacation" , [ "data","address","cat" ] );

console.log(result2); // []
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try below code.

> Please comment if it doesn't satisfy your problem or if you  want more functionality to be added in the code. I will update my answer.

```
function filter( collection , value ,key ){
     for(var obj of collection) {
           if(obj[key[0]][key[1]][key[2]] == value)
           { 
               return obj
           }
     }
     return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the help bro but this answer cannot be dynamic .. for instance the key is only 1 or 2 .

Comment: Okay, can you please add 2-3 test cases with expected output? I will make it dynamic soon. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Clean code using Underscore and ES6 arrow notation.

```js
const equalTo = expected => actual => expected === actual;

function filterDeepValue(collection, value, path) {
    const criterion = _.compose(equalTo(value), _.property(path));
    return _.filter(collection, criterion);
}

const data = [
    {id: 1, data: {name: "sample1", address: {cat: "business"}}},
    {id: 2, data: {name: "sample2", address: {cat: "office"}}},
    {id: 3, data: {name: "sample3", address: {cat: "office"}}},
    {id: 4, data: {name: "sample4", address: {cat: "office"}}},
    {id: 5, data: {name: "sample5", address: {cat: "home"}}},
    {id: 6, data: {name: "sample6", address: {cat: "home"}}},
];

console.log(filterDeepValue(data, 'business', ['data', 'address', 'cat']));
```

```html
<script src="https://underscorejs.org/underscore-umd-min.js"></script>
```